# Simple Linux application converting between colors and hex codes

Tags: linux, color

Can you recommend a simple Linux application that shows the color given a hex code and returns the hex given a color?

[gpick](https://github.com/thezbyg/gpick) comes close by showing the hex code of a picked color, but it does not seem to go the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [**gcolor2**](http://gcolor2.sourceforge.net/)

Free/libre. Gratis. Available in many distribution package archives (e.g., as `gcolor2` [in Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/gcolor2)).

For each color it displays its hex code, its hue/saturation/value values, and its red/green/blue values.

You can

- enter a hex code,
- enter hue/saturation/value and red/green/blue values,
- enter a color name,
- pick a color (from anywhere on the screen),
- choose a color (from the color wheel).

I picked a color from your avatar, the tool tells me that it’s `#FAD7B3`:

[image: Screenshot of gcolor2]

It also allows you to save a color. The list shows the color, its hex code, and a name you can choose.